# Receiving Error from Sharepoint "Server was unable to process request. ---> Site is not configured for Claims Forms Authentication."

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, soa

I am  trying to consume sharepoint webservices using apache httpcomponent client api. 
I am able to perform a httpget and post authentication using ntlm. however attempting to post a request soap xml returns following error

```
    Server was unable to process request. ---> Site is not configured for Claims Forms Authentication.
2014-05-22 07:57:36,241 [main] DEBUG http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/"> <soapenv:Header/> <soapenv:Body> <soap:Login> <soap:username>sansharma</soap:username> <soap:password>******</soap:password> </soap:Login> </soapenv:Body> </soapenv:Envelope>"
2014-05-22 07:57:42,141 [main] DEBUG http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error[\r][\n]"
2014-05-22 07:57:42,142 [main] DEBUG http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Cache-Control: private[\r][\n]"
2014-05-22 07:57:42,142 [main] DEBUG http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8[\r][\n]"
2014-05-22 07:57:42,142 [main] DEBUG http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0[\r][\n]"
2014-05-22 07:57:42,142 [main] DEBUG http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319[\r][\n]"
2014-05-22 07:57:42,142 [main] DEBUG http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "SPRequestGuid: e63e939c-895c-9011-4ed2-bbaeb1a6574b[\r][\n]"
2014-05-22 07:57:42,142 [main] DEBUG http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "request-id: e63e939c-895c-9011-4ed2-bbaeb1a6574b[\r][\n]"
2014-05-22 07:57:42,143 [main] DEBUG http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN[\r][\n]"
2014-05-22 07:57:42,143 [main] DEBUG http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "SPRequestDuration: 5485[\r][\n]"
2014-05-22 07:57:42,143 [main] DEBUG http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "SPIisLatency: 1[\r][\n]"
2014-05-22 07:57:42,143 [main] DEBUG http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Persistent-Auth: false[\r][\n]"
2014-05-22 07:57:42,143 [main] DEBUG http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "X-Powered-By: ASP.NET[\r][\n]"
2014-05-22 07:57:42,144 [main] DEBUG http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 15.0.0.4420[\r][\n]"
2014-05-22 07:57:42,144 [main] DEBUG http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff[\r][\n]"
2014-05-22 07:57:42,144 [main] DEBUG http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "X-MS-InvokeApp: 1; RequireReadOnly[\r][\n]"
2014-05-22 07:57:42,144 [main] DEBUG http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Date: Thu, 22 May 2014 02:27:56 GMT[\r][\n]"
2014-05-22 07:57:42,144 [main] DEBUG http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Content-Length: 443[\r][\n]"
2014-05-22 07:57:42,144 [main] DEBUG http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "[\r][\n]"
2014-05-22 07:57:42,144 [main] DEBUG http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode><faultstring>Server was unable to process request. ---&gt; Site is not configured for Claims Forms Authentication.</faultstring><detail /></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>"
```

Is this a configuration issue. I am trying to invoke the authorization service with login operation.

regards
San Sharma

Comment: No Response :( Have i tagged the question incorrectly ?

Comment: Made some progress and i have finally initiated a interaction.

Comment: Can you please post your answer as I am also getting the same error while consuming Sharepoint webservices using Android

Comment: can you post your solution as i am facing same issue with sharepoint